# Low Latency Audio Playback?

Tags: javascript, html, webkitaudiocontext

Is it possible to achieve low latency audio playback using HTML5? I'm currently using `AudioContext` API. However, I am getting latency of about 4 seconds. Which is way to much for my use case.

```
    if (!window.audioContextInstance) {
      window.audioContextInstance = new webkitAudioContext();
    }
    var context = window.audioContextInstance;

    context.sampleRate = 48000;

    var buffers = [];

    var src = new Float32Array();
    var srcIdx = 0;
    var bufferSize = 2048;

    var sourceNode = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 2);
    sourceNode.onaudioprocess = function(evt) {
      var c0 = evt.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
      var c1 = evt.outputBuffer.getChannelData(1);

      var sample = 0;

      while(sample < bufferSize) {
        if (srcIdx >= src.length) {
          if (!buffers.length) {
            console.log("Warning: Audio Buffer Underflow")
            return;
          }
          src = buffers.shift();
          srcIdx = 0;
        }

        while(sample < bufferSize && srcIdx < src.length) {
          c0[sample] = src[srcIdx++];
          c1[sample] = src[srcIdx++];
          sample++;
        }
      }
    };

    scope.$on('frame', function (event, frame) {          

      while (buffers.length > 1) {
        buffers.shift();
      }

        buffers.push(new Float32Array(frame.data));

      if (buffers.length > 0) {
        sourceNode.connect(context.destination);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [riffwave.js](http://codebase.es/riffwave/) which appears to have much lower than 4s latency.

Comment: Interesting. Any ideas how that would map to a streaming scenario?

Comment: I think you can do an array of buffers like you are doing now and just push them to riffwave with `new RIFFWAVE(yourBufferHere)` and then play them with the dataURI that it gives you